# What technical books should I read to understand clearly Gödel's theorems and their implications for math?

Tags: reference-request, logic, book-recommendation

What technical books should I read to understand clearly Gödel's theorems and their implications for math?

I had a course in university which covered set theory, relations, functions, cardinality (with also Cantor's diagonal argument), boolean algebra viewed as a distributive lattice and Stone's theorem (without the proof), sentential calculus and first order logic (defined with syntax and semantic), tableaux method for both, Hilbert system and deduction theorem (and so, the sequent calculus). Also, without proving it, the professor said that there is a demonstration of soundness and completeness of the Hilbert system (all tautologies and only them can be derived).

After the course I read "Gödel's proof" by Nagel and Newmann and "The universal computer" by Martin Davis. Now I want to understand more. I want to understand how logic can embrace every mathematical reasoning, the difference between an axiomatic theory and a formal system and how a formal system can be built from an axiomatic theory (if it makes sense... maybe I only have confused ideas). And of course i would like to understand the real Gödel's incompleteness theorem proof without someone to simplify it for me (like in Nagel and Newmann's book).

Comment: On Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems, I suggest : [Torkel Franzén, Gödel's theorem : An incomplete guide to its use and abuse](https://books.google.it/books?id=71pK8Zz9Dd8C) (2005) and Peter Smith, [An Introduction to Gödel's Theorems](https://books.google.it/books?id=-SBpYKebkJMC&printsec=frontcover) (2nd ed - 2013).

Comment: On mathematical logic in general, there ara many good textbooks : Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&printsec=frontcover) (5th ed - 2013), George Boolos & John Burgess & Richard Jeffrey, [Computability and Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=nnAhAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (5th ed - 2007), George Tourlakis, [Lectures in Logic and Set Theory. Volume 1 : Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=AHvoluqx7uoC&printsec=frontcover) (2003), Herbert Enderton, A Mathematical Introduction to Logic (2nd ed - 2001).

Comment: A useful available online is Peter Smith's detailed and commented [reading list](http://www.logicmatters.net/tyl/).

Comment: I also suggest the lecture notes "Gödel Without (Too Many) Tears" by the very Peter Smith. They are available from http://www.logicmatters.net/igt/godel-without-tears/

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA You've easily written an answer's worth. Write it as an answer.

Comment: yes, i think so too. He really answered my question with his comments.

Comment: Maybe it is worth mentioning that Peter Smith mentioned in the above comment is also an active [user on this site](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/35151/peter-smith).

Comment: BTW you could probably find several related questions like [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753336/modern-book-on-g%C3%B6dels-incompleteness-theorems-in-all-technical-details) or [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415713/the-way-into-logic-g%C3%B6del-and-turing/). It might be useful to have a look on the list of related questions on the right ->

Comment: Is Nagel's book not enough to make the reader understand Godel's incompleteness theorems? I have bought it but have not read it yet.

Comment: Nagel's book is enough to a superficial understanding, but i wanted a bit more. i think it was worth reading anyway.

Comment: @Andrew - for sure IGT is more complete, and it is quite self-contained. Of course, a full-book on Godel is quite a huge work to digest, but IMO masering the technical side of the topic is fundamental in order to fully understand the philosophocal implications.

Comment: Although I first learnt the incompleteness theorems from Peter Smith's book, in my personal opinion it is not as good as [the computability-based proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2486348/computability-viewpoint-of-godel-rossers-incompleteness-theorem). That linked thread not only is quite self-contained but also proves a full generalization of the theorem, and best of all fits in a single SE post. With your background, you can fully understand the theorem (first half of the post) within a few days, and if you need clarification feel free to ask me!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have to agree with the wise words of Mauro Allegranza :-)

If you want quite a bit of detail in a reasonably accessible form -- and free! -- then there's my notes [Godel Without (Too Many Tears)](http://www.logicmatters.net/igt/godel-without-tears/).

If you want the same basic approach developed more discursively in book form, then there is my [*Introduction to Gödel's Theorems*](http://www.logicmatters.net/igt/). (The 2nd edition is much better than the 1st in the early chapters which relate to your worries, so do look out for that.)

But different people of course like different presentations, so I'd also warmly recommend the books by Epstein and Carnielli, and by Boolos, Burgess and Jeffrey, that you can find details about in §4.2 of [this Guide to logic books](http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/TeachYourselfLogic2015.pdf).

This is a really fun area of logic where you get to Big And Important Results surprisingly quickly and easily. So enjoy!

Comment: Hi Peter - I find your comments throughout MSE helpful and appreciate their succinct nature. You probably have noticed that I have asked you several times for you own opinion regarding the relative math/logic contents of your IGT and WTs versions. Of course, I have looked at both and have no doubt they merit the high regard many commenters throughout MSE have expressed. In your remarks above, you do characterize IGT as more discursive. I did look up 'discursive.' Ironically it has two definitions: 1) tending to digress from the main point, and 2) using reason and argument rather than (cont.)

Comment: intuition. So perhaps you would give me some resolve. I definitely want to read one of the presentations. If I have conviction that IGT has substantially more math/logic content (for the material where they overlap), I will gladly pursue that with focus. Thanks,

Comment: IGT indeed has substantially more math/logic content -- it is discursive in the sense of having more chat about the mathematical results too.